# Object members function gets overridden

Tags: python, oop, python-3.6

When I try to allocate different function to different class members the last declared value gets overriden.

```py
class Object:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class Service:
    @staticmethod
    def get_a_value():
        return 1

    @staticmethod
    def get_b_value(*args, **kwargs):
        return 2

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = Object
        self.b = Object
        self.a.execute = self.get_a_value
        self.b.execute = self.get_b_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Service()

    print(obj.a().execute())
    print(obj.b().execute())
```

The expected output is 1 & 2 but I'm getting both as 2. Not sure what I'm missing here. How can I make sure I can allocate different functions to a.execute and b.execute. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `self.a` and `self.b` are both a reference to `Object`. There's only one `Object`. You're overwriting the same `Object.execute = ...` both times.

Comment: Is there a workaround in this scenario to have different methods allocated to the class members, please ?

Comment: @user2635060 don't assign to the class, assign to different instances.

Comment: None of this looks like good practice in any way, so I'd start by reframing what you're trying to do here instead of asking for "workarounds".

Comment: I'm trying to create my own class for Mocking GCP services.

Comment: @deceze:  Could you please elaborate your point on "None of this looks like good practice in any way"?

Comment: `obj.a()....` seems extremely weird and violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Monkey patching a class's methods also doesn't seem very sane generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about creating specific objects for your `a` and `b` members, with a class deriving from `Object`:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class Service:
    @staticmethod
    def get_a_value():
        return 1

    @staticmethod
    def get_b_value(*args, **kwargs):
        return 2

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        class ObjectA(Object):
            @staticmethod
            def execute():
                return Service.get_a_value()
        class ObjectB(Object):
            @staticmethod
            def execute():
                return Service.get_b_value()

        self.a = ObjectA
        self.b = ObjectB

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Service()

    print(obj.a().execute())
    print(obj.b().execute())
```

This prints

```
1
2
```

Of course this may become slightly more complex if the methods aren't static but this can be easily adapted in the example below where all methods are full non-static methods

```
class Service:
    def get_a_value(self):
        return self.__a_value
    def get_b_value(self):
        return self.__b_value


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__a_value = 1
        self.__b_value = 2

        class ObjectA(Object):
            def execute(myself):
                return self.get_a_value()
        class ObjectB(Object):
            def execute(myself):
                return self.get_b_value()
```

You'll notice that `self` used in `execute` methods refer to instance of `Service` (hence the `myself` first argument in child classes). It works as well, even if no method is static, and can access values of the instance.

With that, you can create full-fledged object interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `obj.a` and `obj.b` contain both a reference to the same class.
So everything you modify on `obj.a` will be reflected in `obj.b`.
What you probably wanted to do is :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = Object()
        self.b = Object()
        self.a.execute = self.get_a_value
        self.b.execute = self.get_b_value
```

Comment: It's imperative that these class members  are callable outside of the class. Hence the reference issue !

Comment: @user2635060 add a `__call__` method to `Object`.

Comment: Continuing with @LouisSaglio 's suggestion, the `__call__` method should return `self`. I still think that this is a bit hacky and you should redesign the code.